# Implementing a Mutex in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex

I have a multi-threaded application (a web app in Tomcat to be exact).  In it there is a class that almost every thread will have its own instance of.  In that class there is a section of code in one method that only ONE thread (user) can execute at a time.  My research has led me to believe that what I need here is a mutex (which is a semaphore with a count of 1, it would seem).

So, after a bit more research, I think what I should do is the following.  Of importance is to note that my lock Object is static.

Am I doing it correctly?

```
public Class MyClass {
  private static Object lock = new Object();
  public void myMethod() {
    // Stuff that multiple threads can execute simultaneously.
    synchronized(MyClass.lock) {
      // Stuff that only one thread may execute at a time.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No reason why it shouldn't work. You could also use a `ReentrantLock` with the same effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, `myMethod` may be executed in any thread, but only in one at a time. That means that there can never be two threads executing this method at the same time. I think that's what you want - so: Yes.

Comment: Thanks!  And the threads will "queue up" waiting to get the lock?  They won't fail immediately if they can't get the lock?

Comment: Yes, they will wait. They even may hang up endless and freeze the application, if the method never returns.

Comment: To avoid the hanging, you may want to look at the Futures pattern/framework, or otherwise have some form of callback system. This would allow those waiting to "take a ticket and do something else while you wait".

Comment: @brainzzy As per JVm implementation, Are these blocked threads blocked using sleep lock or spin lock(busy wait)?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, the multithreading problem comes from mutability - where two or more threads are accessing the same data structure and one or more of them modifies it.

The first instinct is to control the access order using locking, as you've suggested - however you can quickly run into lock contention where your application looses a lot of processing time to context switching as your threads are parked on lock monitors.

You can get rid of most of the problem by moving to immutable data structures - so you return a new object from the setters, rather than modifying the existing one, as well as utilising concurrent collections, such a ConcurrentHashMap / CopyOnWriteArrayList.

Concurrent programming is something you'll need to get your head around, especially as throughput comes from parallelisation in todays modern computing world.

Comment: Thanks. In this case it's not data I'm protecting, it's access to an external hardware resource that only allows one "user" at a time. I agree, concurrent programming is essential and I plan to improve my skills there.

Comment: Valid point - although I would still be cautious about the impact such a bottleneck may have on the system. I spend most of my time tuning high load / throughput applications though

Answer (score 1):

This will allow one thread at a time through the block. Other thread will wait, but no queue as such, there is no guarantee that threads will get the lock in a fair manner. In fact with Biased lock, its unlikely to be fair. ;)

Your lock should be `final` If there is any reason it can't its probably a bug. BTW: You might be able to use `synchronized(MyClass.class)` instead.

Comment: `MyClass.class` is available to other classes and therefore a possible bug source.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm ok with unfairness in this case.  The app is very lightly used, and they are a captive audience (i.e. there's no other app that's competing with mine).